# how can we load and use two same name and type bean in Spring application

Tags: java, spring

I have two jars A and B (spring application) and they are used in another application C (spring application). Now since beans are of the same name, spring will override the bean and would create instance of bean which is loaded last. How can i use both the beans in application C.

I cannot use @qualifier to change the bean name since these two jars are third party.

How can i load both the beans from jar A and jar B that can be used in application C?

Comment: how u load bean? show ur code

Comment: Define a new bean definition for those. Don't scan them (exclude them or at least one) and define it manually.

Comment: ok,so u mean scan one of the config file jar A in this instance and dont import jarB config file and define that manually in application C ?

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib - atTheRate Configuration
@Import({jarAConfig.class,JarBConfig.class})
public clss ApplicationConfig {
}

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
    ApplicationConfig.class);
 }
}

Comment: have you tried to give them a logical component name? you may go through the spring documents how to do this, beans class could be same, a DataSource class, but you can give them different logical component name, DataSourceA - DataSourceB, then you can access them by their logical name

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK: jar A and jar B cannot be modified. is there a way i can give logical names in application C where they are being imported ?

Comment: "beans are of the same name": Do you mean the fully qualified class name (FQCN) is the same, one in jar A, one in jar B? If this is the case, you have no chance to distinguish them. That's not a Spring issue, but java (its classloader) loads the one from the jar which is first in classpath. A minimal chance I see is to work with two different classloaders which different classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the both beans as the following:

```
@Autowired
private List<X> list;
```

Comment: quick question: Would the spring application not override the first bean, i.e. only one bean would be available . how would the list provide both the beans, just a little bit of explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Bean's name is just an identifier to access the bean. In the case, it doesn't mean the bean is overridden but the name is overridden and you are still able to get both of them through the above code.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But this list would give the two beans, we would be required to create a new bean using conditionalbean to distinguish between bean A and bean B. any suggestions ?

Comment: However, I am sure there is a difference between tow beans in terms of their fields, So, to distinguish, you can rely on them.